# Any good Photo Gallery for Joomla! 1.5.23

Tags: jquery, fancybox, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, photo-gallery

New to Joomla and still learning. Can anyone suggest a good lightbox gallery extension for Joomla! 1.5.23?

One that has an admin page to upload, creat and edit albums and create captions or descriptions for each photo and yes of course a lightbox and slideshow capability.

Thanks in advance. Cheers!

Comment: Note that I did look them up. Tons of information out there but none specific to what I wanted. and yup. I'm so stuck with this Joomla version because of the other plugins that only work for this version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Frontpage slideshow](http://www.joomlaworks.net/extensions/commercial-premium/frontpage-slideshow) should work for your needs.

Or their image gallery [Gallery](http://demo.joomlaworks.net/simple-image-gallery-pro)

Answer (score 0):

There are many lightbox jQuery exteanion in joomla u can it  and create your gallery
like 
1.http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=lightbox

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/multimedia/multimedia-display/12103